# Codechef GALACTIK solution

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, disjoint-sets, union-find

[Here's the link for the problem:](https://www.codechef.com/problems/GALACTIK)

I have used union-find algorithm to solve the problem.
Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
#define INT 100000000
unordered_map<ll, ll> parent;
unordered_map<ll, ll> depth;
std::vector<ll> cost;
ll find_set(ll x) {
    if (x == parent[x])return x;
    parent[x] = find_set(parent[x]);
    return parent[x];
}
void union_set(ll x, ll y) {
    /*
    Creating a disjoint set such that the node with smallest cost 
    being the root using union-rank concept. 
    */
    ll rep1 = find_set(x), rep2 = find_set(y);
    if (depth[rep1] > depth[rep2])parent[rep1] = rep2;
    else if (depth[rep2] >= depth[rep1])parent[rep2] = rep1;
}
int main() {
    ll n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    ll c[m + 1][3];
    for (ll i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        cin >> c[i][1] >> c[i][2]; //Accepting the edges
    }
    for (ll i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        parent[i] = i;
        cin >> depth[i];
        if (depth[i] < 0)depth[i] = INT;
        /*we assume that each negative cost is replaced by a very 
          large positive cost.*/ 
    }
    for (ll i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        union_set(c[i][1], c[i][2]);
    }
    set<ll> s;
    std::vector<ll> v;
    //storing representatives of each connected component
    for (auto i = 1; i <= n; i++)s.insert(depth[find_set(i)]);
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)v.push_back(*it);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (s.size() == 1) {
        //Graph is connected if there is only 1 connected comp
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    bool flag = false;
    ll p = 0;
    for (ll i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] == INT) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        p += (v[0]+v[i]);
    }
    if (flag)cout << -1 << endl;
    else cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Logic used in my program:
To find the answer, take the minimum value of all the valid values in a connected component.Now to make the graph connected, Take the minimum value of all the values we got from the above step and make edge from that node to all the remaining nodes.If graph is already connected than answer is 0.if there exists a connected component where all nodes are not valid to be chosen, than answer is not possible (-1).

But this solution is not accepted?What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your algo sounds correct, so I suggest you to use various simple test cases and debugger for debug.

Comment: Elaborate on "not accepted", does it get wrong answer, runtime exception, or time limit exceeded?

Comment: @pkpnd I'm getting wrong answer.But the program works fine for sample test cases.